# Trouble switching to Dvorak on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout, system-settings, dvorak

I've decided to switch to Dvorak on my Ubuntu machine, but I'm having some trouble:

First, I attempted to do this through the GUI -- System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> add layout (plus sign) -> English(programmer Dvorak). This didn't work at first, so I restarted my machine. It seemed to work at the password prompt (if only because QWERTY did not), but I couldn't get it to accept my password. I used the virtual keyboard option to enter my password with mouse clicks (the virtual keyboard was using the programmer's Dvorak Standard) and was able to get in that way. Once logged in, however, I was back to QWERTY.

Second, I tried to switch on the command prompt -- $ loadkeys /usr/lib/kbd/keytables/dvorak.map
The error message I received was "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've looked for a solution for these problems, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was my .Xmodmap file. Once deleted, the GUI approach worked.